# Problems with French encoding in Jquery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

i spent 3 hours to find solutions but it's unsuccessfully. 
I send variable `familie` with "pompe **à** injection-injecteurs" thru AJAX POST and i'm always getting  value "pompe **Ã** injection-injecteurs".  I have tried to use utf8_encoding, mb_strtolower and more, more ..... but no luck.

```
var familie = "<?php echo $familie ?>";
console.log(familie) 
marque = $('#car_marque').find(":selected").text();
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  data: {familie: familie, marque: marque },
  dataType: "text",
  url: "index.php?route=product/autres/cars",
  success: function (data) {
```

Console.log output: "pompe **à** injection-injecteurs".

Comment: Did you try save the html file (or php) as utf-8 or windows-1252 (I don't know) of instead ansi?

Comment: Do you have the corresponding **meta tag** in your HTML page: `<meta charset="utf-8"> `?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following:

```
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  data: {familie: familie, marque: marque },
  contentType:"application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8",
  dataType: "text",
  url: "index.php?route=product/autres/cars",
  success: function (data) {
```